# do i need a break after return in my function?

Tags: c++, oop

this is a function in my code:

```
bool same_community(string s1, string s2)//check if student 1 & student 2 are in the same community
{
for(int i=0;i<number_of_communities;i++)    
    if(community[i].contains(s1) && community[i].contains(s2))
    {
        return true;
        break;
    }
return false
}
```

is the break after return true needed?

Comment: No, but I suggest better indentation :-) Ah... And I even suggest always using {} even for single liners. And of passing s1 and s2 as `const string&`

Comment: You not have to break after return.

Comment: You will never reach the break! Dependent on your compiler (settings) you will get a warning or error, too.

Comment: And if you don't get the warning, it's a good indication you should compile with settings that give more warning or if necessary change the compiler :-)

Comment: Note that if break was accessible, it would mean that then return false would be reached, and thus your initial return true would serve no purpose. Further, it would mean that a return statement would be a no-op inside a method.

Answer (score 5):

No.  It's dead code and will very likely be removed by your compiler's optimizer.  Remove it, since it reduces your code's readability.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `return` statement is enough to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The break is not needed.  The return is enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to. The return expression makes the execution flow leave the function. Anything after return won't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to use `break`.  It is used to terminate a loop early, but `return` (within a subroutine) will also terminate any loop it is inside of.  Anything that follows `return` is dead code.